# What is the propper way to get a char's code point?

Tags: java, unicode, char, codepoint

I need to do some stuff with codepoints and a newline.  I have a function that takes a `char`'s codepoint, and if it is `\r` it needs to behave differently.  I've got this:

```
if (codePoint == Character.codePointAt(new char[] {'\r'}, 0)) {
```

but that is very ugly and ***certainly*** not the right way to do it.  What is the correct method of doing this?

<sub>(I know that I could hardcode the number `13` (decimal identifier for `\r`) and use that, but doing that would make it unclear what I am doing...)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If* you know that all your input is going to be in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 to U+FFFF) then you can just use:

```
char character = 'x';
int codePoint = character;
```

That uses the implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, as specified in JLS 5.1.2:

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - ...
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
>
> ...
>
> A widening conversion of a char to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the char value to fill the wider format.

However, a `char` is only a UTF-16 code *unit*. The point of `Character.codePointAt` is that it copes with code points outside the BMP, which are composed of a *surrogate pair* - two UTF-16 code units which join together to make a single character.

From [JLS 3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1):

> The Unicode standard was originally designed as a fixed-width 16-bit character encoding. It has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, using the hexadecimal U+n notation. Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. To represent the complete range of characters using only 16-bit units, the Unicode standard defines an encoding called UTF-16. In this encoding, supplementary characters are represented as pairs of 16-bit code units, the first from the high-surrogates range, (U+D800 to U+DBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (U+DC00 to U+DFFF). For characters in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF, the values of code points and UTF-16 code units are the same.

If you need to be able to cope with that more complicated situation, you'll need the more complicated code.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, you could simply cast the `char` to an `int`, something like this

```
char ch = '\r';
int codePoint = (int) ch;
System.out.println(codePoint);
```

Output is

```
13
```

Comment: Ah, so that is what can be done.  I wouldn't have guessed that; I was looking for methods in `Character` to do that.  This seems to be working for what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but neither of the existing answers actually answers the question, including the accepted answer.

You can simply compare a code point with a char directly.

```
if (codePoint == '\r')
```